# "clopen" terminology: acceptable?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I like the term "clopen" (a set which is both open and closed in a topological space), though an instructor of mine hated it when I used it recently. (Approximately, "never, ever use that again.") Is this common? Was the term introduced relatively recently, so perhaps age has something to do with it, or is this a random occurrence?

Really, are there enough people who dislike or don't know "clopen" that I should switch to the barely longer "closed and open"?

Comment: To my knowledge, clopen is completely standard.

Comment: I thought it was standard, but I guess you should avoid saying it in front of that instructor. :)

Comment: I prefer not to use *monoide* (monoid in Italian), because it reminds too much a vulgar word in our local dialect; but I wouldn't correct anybody using the word. The term *clopen* has been widely used for decades and I see no reason for rejecting it. But *when in Rome do as Romans do*. `;-)`

Comment: The one disadvantage is that *clopen* is hard to translate (some people try to introduce *abgeschloffen* (=abgeschlossen + offen) in German, but that is really non-standard and would cause me to react like your instructor), but that shouldn't bother. I think that this specifically coined portmanteau word is helpful also because avoiding "closed and open", which is a contradiction in *everyday* language, allows us to read more fluently

Comment: I wish there was a term like this in french… We have to write _ouvert et fermé_ every time.

Comment: @Oliver How about *ouvermé*? ☺

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Well, it doesn't sound that bad actually!

Comment: Sometimes in Dutch we used (semi-jokingly) "opgesloten" (open + gesloten) which already means "locked up", but mostly we borrowed clopen as a word. It's pretty old, but even my instructors in the nineties mentioned that there are some "haters"... So personal preferences...

Comment: The consensus seems to be this was a random occurrence and "clopen" is fine.

For what it's worth some non-mathematicians I've known have laughed at it for sounding silly and contradictory, so maybe that's the source of the instructor's objection.

Comment: I think that it is ok und useful, but I might think differently about it if English was my native language.